# How to commit transaction on an after update event trigger?

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I'm new here in dba.stackexchange.com, so if I were to make any mistake, my apologies in advance.

I kinda confused on how trigger work. So I have a trigger called `updcredaccess` on table `A` that updates table `B` on after update event. Then I need the currently updated value on table `A` for other table to inspect, so I used `autonomous transaction trigger`. But then when I update, the value on table `A` doesn't seems to be updated with the current value.

Here is my table

```
Table A

id varchar(10)

val varchar(10)
```

Table B
id varchar(10)
val varchar(10)

and here is my trigger
Table A trigger

```
create or replace trigger updA  
after update on A  
for each row  
declare  
pragma autonomous_transaction;  
cek varchar2(5);  
begin  
commit;  
select val into cek from A where id = :new.id;  
dbms_output.put_line('Cek cek: ' || cek);  
update B set val = :new.val where id = :new.id;  
commit;  
end;  
/
```

And for table B
 Table B trigger

```
create or replace trigger updB  
after update on B  
for each row  
declare  
v varchar2(5);  
begin  
select val into v from B where id = :new.id;  
-- Some other pl/sql code --  
end;  
/
```

I then input 2 records like

```
 insert all into A values ('a', 'false') into A values ('b', 'false') select * from dual;
```

Then i tried this code

```
 update A set val = 'true'
```

The query works fine. But I was so confused because at the log console it says

> Cek cek: false (The output log at trigger A)

The value still hasn't changed.

So, what I need is the current new `val` value at the 2nd trigger, so It can be processed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect B to be updated, when you inserted a row with a different id? Actually, your `INSERT ALL` does not insert anything into `B`.

The above works fine after fixing your trigger and sample data:

```
create or replace trigger updB  
after update on B  
for each row  
declare  
v varchar2(5);  
begin  
  v := :new.val;
end;  
/
```

This is how you reference the new val in the trigger, not with a select. Your original trigger would run into the infamous `ORA-04091` "table is mutating" error.

```
SQL> insert all into A values ('a', 'false') into b values ('a', 'false') select * from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> update A set val = 'true';
Cek cek: false

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from a;

ID         VAL
---------- ----------
a          true

SQL> select * from b;

ID         VAL
---------- ----------
a          true
```

For the output:

Your `updA` trigger runs in an autonomous transaction. When you select val from `A`, your original update is still not finished (commited), you will see the old value. Fixing your trigger for `A`:

```
create or replace trigger updA  
after update on A  
for each row  
declare  
pragma autonomous_transaction;  
cek varchar2(5);  
begin  
commit;  
  cek := :new.val;  
dbms_output.put_line('Cek cek: ' || cek);  
update B set val = :new.val where id = :new.id;  
commit;  
end;  
/
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer :D Above code works for me without error, but it doesn't solve my problem... As questioned above "Then I need the currently updated value on table A for other table to inspect", "Other table" here means Table B to inspect... So i need the currently new value at Table A to be inspected by trigger on Table B, I used "Select val into v from A where id = :new.id", but it always returns old value..., how to get the current value...?